# how does one tell one $(document).ready() call from another?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I create an iframe dynamically to use as a place to do a form based API call.

```
$('<iframe>').attr({
    name : "secret_sending_iframe",
    src : "#",
    style : "visibility:hidden; width:0px; height:0px;"
    }).appendTo("#recordingControl");
```

this has the side effect of causing my $(document).ready() to fire again. This is understandable as it's telling me that my iframe is ready, but now I need to distinguish the initial document ready from this new document ready. Is there some way to tell that it's the iframe that just became ready other than testing for the negative existence of the iframe to tell that it's the first call to .ready()?

BTW - testing for $("iframe") in the $(document).ready() call returned [] which I did not expect. So the best solution for me was to use the window.location.href, see below...

Comment: creating an iframe dynamically should NOT cause $() to be called again. you're doing something else here

Comment: Following on from @Scott's comment, you're most likely including the JS file in the iframe source as well.

Comment: So, the iframe src tag is "#" id did this to avoid having to create and then link to an empty page. I think that the "#" src tag must be reloading the enclosing page again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each frame has it's own separate javascript context and it's own separate `$(document).ready()`.  So, I don't think you're seeing the same `$(document).ready()` get called more than once unless you have multiple calls to `$(document).ready()` in the same document.  Otherwise, each time it would be called would be a different document.

If you have identical code and you need to know which one is being called, you can always look at the `window.location` object to see what page/frame you're in.  To understand your situation, I'd suggest adding this to each one:

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

And, then you can separate out which is which.

Comment: This works well, as the second time around the href has the "#" char at the end as that's what I set the src tag to. (see example in question post)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to deal with this is to set a global variable in your JS before the $(document).ready() function, and test for it within:

```
var run_doc_ready = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    if (!run_doc_ready) {
       ...
       run_doc_ready = 1;
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need to protect yourself from this unless you yourself are inserting multiple `.ready()` calls in your own code.  Looking at the jQuery code it looks to me like it already protects against firing of any individual ready() handler more than once per document.

Comment: @jfriend00 - the duplicate ready call is coming from the iframe loading the same page again, I am using a src tag of "#", see my comment up top.